# i am unable to get the value of session

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am setting the session value
but when i try to get it on other page its null

i am storing session in sql

previously it was wrking fine
and still some session values are wrking ok

but when i add a new its null while getting it

Comment: Please provide some more details about your problem. Like some code. 
Thanks

Comment: need some more information to help. You may need to check if you have setup correctly the cookies, if session is enable, what are the parameters for sessions, and other small thinks

Comment: Session is not available at certain times in the page lifecycle. WHERE are you trying to access Session? In a HttpModule or HttpHandler? On Page_PreInit, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small hint, but maybe it is helpful:

You've said that you store your session-object in Sql-Server - is it marked as `Serializable`? As this is necessary when Sessions are not inside Memory but StateServer or DqlServer?

Example:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Account
    {
         ...
    }
```